# Estimating river stream from observing boat speed distribution going up/down stream

Tags: correlation

I am looking for the method that estimates a parameter to maximise the correlation between two distributions.

I am measuring the speed of a rowing boat that goes up and down a river. The crew goes at different speeds - doing fast 500m and then goes slower again, for example. Because of the river flow going downstream tends to be faster. Is it possible to estimate the river flow from this data? The goal is to normalise the speed knowing the river flow.

Below is an example:

- the top graph shows the rowing stroke rate per minute (not relevant here)
- the second graph shows the speed (m/s)
- the bottom graph shows the speed distribution
- all data is split between going up and downstream.

[image]

My general idea is that shifting the two speed distributions such that their product (correlation) is maximised would give me an indication of the speed. What is the statistical method to do that?

I am aware that vastly different movements up and downstream (as happened to an extent in the example) will create uncertainty; likewise we could assume that other factors are at play like wind, which I would ignore for now.

Comment: This will get more complicated if the boat speed is confounded with the direction - do you expected systematic differences in the upstream and downstream trips? If all the upstream trips are sprints and the downstream trips are recoveries, for example, you might see similar distributions that could be interpreted as little to no current.

Comment: The typical pattern (and current assumption) is that boats do similar things going up and downstream. In the general case you can construct a case where your estimate would be completely off. An indication what boats are doing is the stroke rate - there is a strong correlation between stroke rate and speed. You could also say if movement patterns are not similar to begin with, don't even try. Currently I just look at the difference between the two highest peaks - half their distance is the flow. I come here for a better foundation.

Comment: Unless you make very strong simplifying assumptions about the river speeds, you have no hope of estimating either one of the speeds (boat or river).  You can change the river speed at time $t$ by $+s(t)$ and the boat's speed relative to the river at time $t$ by $-s(t)$ without changing any of the data, while profoundly changing the total river flow.  Thus, your estimates will be uncertain relative to any *function* $s$ that varies within physically reasonable bounds.

Comment: You would assume that the river speed is constant. Clearly it would be easier to measure river speed explicitly but I was hoping to find a method that can deduce it under some explicit assumptions from noisy data like this. In the data shown the river speed was probably around 0.1m/s (based on observations on the day and looking at the two peaks around 5m/s in the distribution).

Comment: It *sounds* like you are asking for half the mean upstream boat speed minus mean downstream boat speed, then.  It's hard to tell how this might be related to a "correlation between two distributions," though, so I'm still unsure what you're looking for.

Comment: The stream add or subtracts a constant amount of speed from the true boat speed. So I would expect that the speed distributions of the boat going up/down stream are shifted relative to each other by twice that amount of speed. To recover the shift I imagine you could multiply both distributions with one shifted (like in autocorrelation); the shift that maximises the product gives you twice the flow speed.